# how to disable p2p in android init.rc

Tags: android, p2p, init, bootloader

Hello I'm trying to stop the p2p service from starting, and I have tried using the command below in an included init.projectnamehere.rc

```
on property:net.wifi.p2p=1
class main
net.wifi.p2p stop
```

I have also tried, this in the build.prop

```
sys.settings.global wifi_p2p_enable=false
```

I also tried

```
setprop net.wifi.p2p=DISABLED
```

My guess is I'm on the right track since I once disabled the entire wifi mod.

**NOTES:**
yes in the init.rc I have the `import init.projectnamehere.rc` line.
Android 4.2.2 SDK 17

Answer (score 0):

in /system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf add this:
p2p_disabled=1

or in "human" language:

adb remount 
adb shell echo 'p2p_disabled=1' >> /system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf